# How to Uninstall-Module of older version

Tags: powershell

The system appears to have two (2) versions of PowerShellGet module installed.

```
Script     2.2        PowerShellGet
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet
```

How can I uninstall the older version? The `Uninstall-Module` command appears to be looking in the `2.2` directory. Why is that?

```
>Uninstall-Module -Name 'PowerShellGet' -RequiredVersion '1.0.0.1'
PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'PowerShellGet'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2\PSModule.psm1:12655 char:21
+ ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage
```

When I try to specify the older version, it reports the new version.

```
>Get-Module -FullyQualifiedName @{ModuleName="PowerShellGet";ModuleVersion="1.0.0.1"}

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     2.2        PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability...}

>($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).ToString()
5.1.14409.1018
>(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't that uninstall something with `PowerShellGet` if it wasn't installed with `PowerShellGet`.

**Long answer:**

`PowerShellGet v1.0.0.1` was installed as a part of Windows, and not using `PowerShellGet` (naturally). Hence, why you can't use `PowerShellGet` to `Uninstall-Module` it.

`PowerShellGet v2.2` on the other hand, *is* installed with `PowerShellGet` and so you *can* `Uninstall-Module` it. You can also update it etc.

If you really want to uninstall the v1.0.0.1 version, you have to follow these
[Steps](http://shaulov.us/2018/01/13/upgrading-powershellget-1-0-0-1-to-the-latest-version/):

> 1. Browse to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\`
> 2. Go into `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowershellGet` folder, and delete the sub- folder `1.0.0.1`
> 3. Then do the same for `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement`, delete the
>      sub-folder `1.0.0.1`

Comment: There are also `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1` directories.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer. It would seem that I do not really need to delete the 1.0.0.1 version. Will the most current version version be loaded unless using `Import-Module -*Version`?

Comment: Yes you will get the most recent version by default unless you specify a version.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a special situation with PowerShellGet.

However in general, i use this script here:

```
$ModuleName = 'YourModuleName';
$Latest = Get-InstalledModule $ModuleName; 
Get-InstalledModule $ModuleName -AllVersions | Sort-Object -Descending {[Version]$_.Version} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Uninstall-Module -WhatIf
```

Remember to remove the "-WhatIf" tag once you're happy with the result.

Credits to Eclipses:
https://www.myerrorsandmysolutions.com/how-to-uninstall-older-versions-of-a-powershell-module-installed/

Comment: This doesn't work all the time (because the Version field is typed as a string, and ("1.9.0" -gt "1.10.0"))

Something like this works better:

Get-InstalledModule | ForEach-Object { Get-InstalledModule $_.Name -AllVersions | Sort-Object -Descending {[Version]$_.Version} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Uninstall-Module -Verbose }

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would dogpile on and give my latest findings on all of this!

It looks like the story doesn't end here.

As of 1/24/2024, Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet now replaces PowerShellGet and PackageManagement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/powershellget/install-powershellget?view=powershellget-3.x

This got me to thinking, if Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet replaces PowerShellGet and PackageManagement, then why do I still need to have them installed?

It turns out, the 'old' commands such as Find-Command, Find-Module, Update-Module, Update-Script, etc. in PowerShellGet and PackageManagement are replaced with Get-PSResource, UpdatePSResource, etc. (see the new command replacements at):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.psresourceget/about/about_psresourceget?view=powershellget-3.x

So if you still want to use the 'old' commands, you can keep PowerShellGet and PackageManagement installed, but if you want to force yourself to learn the 'new' way of doing things, the you can remove PowerShellGet and PackageManagement, so that only the 'new' commands are available to you!

Also, it looks like in order to get to Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet, especially on a new install of Windows PowerShell 5.1, you would first start off with version 1.0.0.1 of PowerShellGet and PackageManagement, point to the PSGallery so that you can get updated versions of PowerShellGet and PackageManagement, and then you will be able to pull down Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of completeness, on Windows systems there are often both 64-bit and 32-bit directory paths.

```
>(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path "$Env:SystemDrive/" -Filter '1.0.0.1' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1
C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1
C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules can also be found in System32.  Huge headache for me when I was only looking in 32/64bit Program Files trying to figure out how certain modules were still loading.  Sneaky Microsoft.

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules